# How to rename a file to a substring within the filename?

Tags: python

I'm trying to rename the files in a directory that have the substring "Episode.26" by truncating the words before and after the substring

e.g. 'The.Vision.of.Escaflowne.**Episode.26**.Eternal.Love.1080p.Dual.Audio.Bluray [BC6DDF99]**.mkv'**

The value to be found will always be **Episode.##** (## two digits)

Desired result: **Episode.26.mkv**

Current result: **Episode.26**.Eternal.Love.1080p.Dual.Audio.Bluray [BC6DDF99]**.mkv**'

I removed the first **n** characters using python; but, I don't know how to isolate 'Episode.26' efficiently

```
import os

key = "Episode."

for filename in os.listdir("."):
  if(key in filename):
    index = filename.index(key)
    os.rename(filename, filename[index:])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your filename is always separated by periods then **[`split()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html)** might be sufficient:

```
import os

ext = ".mkv"
ndl = "Episode"

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if ext in filename and ndl in filename:
        num = filename.split(ndl, 1)[1].split(" ")[0].split(".")[1]
        epi = "{}.{}{}".format(ndl, num, ext)
        os.rename(filename, epi)
```

This should split the name after your needle ("`ndl`") grab the episode number and rename the file; it should also handle filenames that include spaces in addition to periods or if "Episode.26" is at the end of the string (eg. `Some.Movie.Episode.26 [BC6DDF99].mkv`).

**Result**:

```
Episode.26.mkv
```

Answer (score 2):

If u'r sure there's two digits after "Episode.", then u can code like this. Otherwise, i'm afraid u should use [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to get what u want.

```
import os

key = 'Episode'
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    try:
        index = filename.index(key)
        _, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        new_name = filename[index:index+len(key)+3] + file_extension
        os.rename(filename, new_name)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **regular expressions**, capture the episode number and file extension and create the new name using such data:

### Code

```python
import re
import os

key = "Episode"
regexp = re.compile('.*%s\.(\d\d).*\.(.+)' % key)

for filename in os.listdir("."):
  match = regexp.match(filename)

  if match:
    episode, file_ext = match.group(1), match.group(2)
    new_name = key + episode + '.' + file_ext

    os.rename(filename, new_name)
```

This way is more cleaner and flexible. REs are very powerfull. Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, you can use search instead of match and remove .* at the beginning of re

```
import re
import os

key = "Episode"
regexp = re.compile('%s\.(\d\d).*\.(.+)' % key)

for filename in os.listdir("."):
  match = regexp.search(filename)

  if match:
    episode, file_ext = match.group(1), match.group(2)
    new_name = key + episode + '.' + file_ext

    os.rename(filename, new_name)
```